# Dictionary out of a complex nested object

Tags: c#, asp.net, linq

I have DTOs like this

```
public class Obj1
{
    public string a1 { get; set; };
    public Obj2[] a2 { get; set; };
}
public class Obj2
{
    public string b1 { get; set; };
    public Obj3[] b2 { get; set; };
}
public class Obj3
{
    public string Key  { get; set; };
}
```

So, the object will be like

```
Obj1 o = new Obj1
{
    a1="a";
    a2=new[]
    {
        new Obj2
        {
            b1="b";
            b2=new[]
            {
                new Obj3
                {
                   Key="c";
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

I have Obj1. How can I group it in the form of dictionary of type

```
IDictionary<string, IEnumerable<Obj2>>
```

where Key is in Obj3.

I tried using GroupBy but did not get the relevant result.

Comment: " tried using GroupBy but did not get the relevant result." please post this code

Comment: how would you decide in which group Obj2 goes if it has multiple Obj3-Keys? like: `Obj2 b1 = { c1, c3}` and `Obj2 b2 = { c3, c1}` ? do you want them duplicated? or will the group now be a combination of c1+c3 ?

Comment: @MongZhu It can be duplicated.

Comment: "It can be duplicated." actually for me it seems that it is not optional. you have to decide which way you want to go. And you need to tell us, because this is a very important point

Comment: Yes, we must duplicate it. @MongZhu

Answer (score 1):

If I understand the end goal - co combine all `Obj2` by all child `Obj3.Key` and after fixing the code to make it compile you can use `SelectMany` into intermediate data structure with aggregation with `GroupBy`:

```cs
var dictionary = o.a2
    .SelectMany(o2 => o2.b3.Select(o3 => (o3.Key, o2)))
    .GroupBy(t => t.Key)
    .ToDictionary(g => g.Key, g => g.ToList());
```

Answer (score 0):

Im not quite sure, but your class "obj2" instead of having 2 properties, you can make it with one property of Dictionary with a string key and Ienumerable value, so your variable could look like this.
Dictionary<string, Dictionary<string, Ienumerable>> and you can add "obj3" as a value or key.